# Is it possible to build a web application with only client side languages?

Tags: javascript, database, web-applications, point-of-sale

Is it possible to build a POS (point of sale) web application (local host) for my shop with only client side languages (HTML, CSS, JS) with integrated database (mysql, sqlite, etc.)?

Comment: Check the nodejs framework.

Comment: like balaG said, you won't be able to keep everything client side only. but I do disagree on his point with little interactive pages. angularjs could be a solution for your application. maybe a MEAN stack (meanjs.org) is also something to check out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep data in any database like MySQL, then you have to use some Server-Side technology (PhP, ASP.NET or JSP etc.).

By using client-side languages only static and little interactive pages can be created.

So my answer is NO. You can not create a site for your shop by using only client-side scripting languages if you want to maintain database.